# Divs next to each other for Navigation

Tags: css, image, html, navigation

**Edit: Now that flexbox has become basically universally supported, use flexbox!**

I want to have 3 `div` objects next to each other for my navigation bar. There should be an image in the right one to begin the navigation bar, one on the end to finish it, and the middle part should be as wide as it needs to be to fit all the text in. And the navigation bar should be in the middle of the page. I am not sure if I did it totally wrong, because it won't really work at all. This is the code I already got.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="navLeft"></div>
    <div class="navMiddle">
        <ul>
            <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navRight"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.navigation {
    margin: auto;
    height: 70;
}

.navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
}

.navLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 13;
    height: 70;
    background: url(../images/Nav_L.png);
}

.navMiddle {
    height: 70;
    background: url(../images/Nav_Mid.png) repeat-x;
}

.navRight {
    float: right;
    width: 13;
    height: 70;
    background: url(../images/Nav_R.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `width: calc(100% - 26px);` will take the remaining width of `.navMiddle`.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalkin/cREzj/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

First of all there are many errors in your css.

```
width:13;      // WRONG

width:13px;    //CORRECT
```

any `width`, `height`, `margin`, `padding` which is more than 0 should either have `px`, `em` or `%`

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to diagnose this problem without seeing what is happening. I would imagine that you need to set a width on your navigation class. It might help to float all three of your classes (navLeft, navMiddle, and navRight) in the same direction (most likely left). If you want to vertically center all of this, you will most likely need to make sure whatever is containing this navigation has a height of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `inline-block` instead of floating. it give's you better handling.

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3WHL/1/)

BTW: values other than `0` need to have a value, so `70` needs to be `70px`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I highly recommend save yourself the headaches with hard coding all of this and utilize the **flexbox**. It makes a much cleaner solution and gives alot more control with out so much hard coding.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/an-introduction-to-css-flexbox/

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: not supported with older browsers, and needs a lot of vendor specifics.

Comment: yea yea but he never said what he needed this for. Might help

Comment: I'm not saying its bad.. I'm just pointing some relevant points.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can place the <div class="navRight"> before <div class="navMiddle">

```
<div class="navigation">
<div class="navLeft"></div>
<div class="navRight"></div> <!-- place navRight div here -->
<div class="navMiddle">
    <ul>
        <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navLeft, .navMidlle, .navRight{display:inline;}
```

I'd suppose that would work, you can try to test it out. Delete the float:left; and float:right; in your css also.

Comment: Congrats on your first StackOverflow answer!  In the future, if you can try the answer out yourself to verify that it works before posting, that would make it even more helpful.